# Typescript i18next does not satisfy the constraint 'string | TemplateStringsArray NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to type an array of objects to be translated with i18next, but the following message occurs in variable navItems where I'm declaring the i18next to then iterate the array `Type 'NavItemProps[]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | TemplateStringsArray'. Property 'raw' is missing in type 'NavItemProps[]' but required in type 'TemplateStringsArray'`

and inside the map the Property 'map' `message does not exist on type 'string | object | (string | object)[]'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'`

I used it as a reference for typing the i18next through this link, but without success [i18next: Map an array of objects in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625749/i18next-map-an-array-of-objects-in-typescript)

**Component**

```
const DesktopNav = ({hasBackground}: DesktopNavProps) => {
  const {t} = useTranslation('navbar')
  const linkColor = useColorModeValue(
    hasBackground ? 'black' : 'white',
    'gray.200'
  )
  const linkHoverColor = useColorModeValue('gray.400', 'white')
  const popoverContentBgColor = useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.800')

  const navItems = t<NavItemProps[]>('menu', {returnObjects: true})

  return (
    <C.List display={'flex'} alignItems={'center'}>
      {navItems?.map((item: NavItemProps, index: number) => (
        <C.ListItem key={index}>
          <C.Popover trigger={'hover'} placement={'bottom-start'}>
            <C.PopoverTrigger>
              <C.Link
                p={3}
                href={item.href ?? '#'}
                fontWeight={500}
                color={linkColor}
                _hover={{
                  textDecoration: 'none',
                  color: linkHoverColor,
                }}
              >
                {item.label}
              </C.Link>
            </C.PopoverTrigger>
          </C.Popover>
        </C.ListItem>
      ))}
    </C.List>
  )
}
```

**Interface**

```
interface NavItemProps {
  label: string
  href?: string
  subLabel?: string
  children?: Array<NavItemProps>
}
```

**Json file translate**

```
{
  "menu": [
    {
      "label": "jobs",
      "href": "/"
    },
    {
      "label": "about",
      "href": "/about"
    },
     {
      "label": "Blog",
      "href": "/blog"
    },
    {
      "label": "contact",
      "href": "/contact"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `NavItemProps` interface be something like `interface NavItemProps { label: string; href: string; }` instead? That's the format of the items under `menu` in your JSON.

Comment: @juliomalves no, I am already informing you that the href, sublabel and children props are optional

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't say when exactly (in which release) this happened, but apparently the order of generics for `t` function has changed in react-i18next types definition, compared to the link you're refering. The current definition is:

```
<
    TKeys extends TFuncKey<N> | TemplateStringsArray extends infer A ? A : never,
    TDefaultResult extends TFunctionResult = string,
    TInterpolationMap extends object = StringMap
  >(
    key: TKeys | TKeys[],
    options?: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string,
   ): TFuncReturn<N, TKeys, TDefaultResult>;
```

As you see, the first type refers to keys and the second one to results. So I guess you could use it like this:

```
const navItems = t<string, NavItemProps[]>('menu', { returnObjects: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever since i18next version 23 you need to pass 3 type arguments to the `t` function. First is the type of the key, second is for the options you pass, and third is for the return type.

You would need to write:

```js
const navItems = t<string, { returnObjects: true }, NavItemProps[]>('menu', { returnObjects: true });
```

It's very verbose and you might want to make your own reusable function to reduce the boilerplate.

Solution at: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/2151